# Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key

Tags: java, google-play, apk, keystore, android-app-bundle

My app is already on google play and I want to update it. Before this I was uploading `.apk` file to upload but now I want to update it to `.aab`. Google Play asks to provide it with encrypted key and gave some directions, I followed the steps but I ended up at this error.

```
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 
RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
```

[image: The problem]

I have searched how to solve this issue but only thing I found is **update your jdk version**

[image: Java Version]

and as you can see my jdk version is upto date.
What should I do? Thanks for the help :).